# Trigger On Opportunity Stage based on Opplineitem

Tags: apex, triggercontext, trigger

I have custom field **`Invoice Date`** in **`OpportunityLineitem`** when this is left blank it should show error using trigger when trying to update Opportunity with Opportunity **`stagename`** as **`closed won`**.

I tried the following way:

```
trigger OpportunityStageWon on Opportunity(before insert, before update) {
    set<Id> Oid = new set<id>();
    for (Opportunity o: Trigger.new) {
        Oid.add(o.id);
    }
    List<OpportunityLineItem> OLI = [Select id, name, Invoice_Date1__c from OpportunityLineItem where Opportunityid =: Oid];
    for (Opportunity o: Trigger.New) {
        for(OpportunityLineItem ol : OLI){
            if (o.StageName == 'Closed Won' && ol.Invoice_Date1__c == null) {
                o.StageName.addError('Your custom error message');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: Given code is not complete.There could be multiple line items related to one opportunity.Specify exactly what issue you are having?

Comment: Very true .It's not working.My question how do I achieve this?

Comment: I tried creating list<Opplineitem>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below Code

```
trigger OpportunityStageWon on Opportunity(before insert, before update) {
    set<Id> Oid = new set<id>();
    for (Opportunity o: Trigger.new) {
        Oid.add(o.id);
    }
    List<OpportunityLineItem> OLI = [Select id, name, Invoice_Date1__c from OpportunityLineItem where Opportunityid =: Oid];
    for (Opportunity o: Trigger.New) {
        for(OpportunityLineItem ol : OLI){
            if (o.StageName == 'Closed Won' && ol.Invoice_Date1__c == null) {
                o.StageName.addError('Your custom error message');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

You can refer below link for Trigger.New and Trigger.Old Difference

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000098JAIAY

Hope this might helps...

Comment: It helped.I have a query for you.If I use tigger.old  in both loops I am getting this errr"System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors: Trigger.OpportunityStageWon: line 10, column 1" why?

Comment: You should take the Trigger.New only. Because you are giving the before insert and before update for the Trigger....... Trigger.Old is naturally used for the Delete Operations....

Comment: In simple words Trigger.new returns new value of records and Trigger.old returns old value of records. Trigger.new works in case of insert and update both and Trigger.old works in case of update and delete both. For update you can use both as per your need.Clearrrrrrrrrrr

Comment: Yes, For Update also, Trigger.Old will be used in minimal cases... But if you are using Delete means, You should use only the Trigger.Old...

Comment: interesting.. can we get the Id in before insert ? if id is not generated then how come you get the OLI for that opportunity ?

Comment: Haha.:). No ratan... I too forgot.. Sorry

Comment: But Practically, What you said is not possible @ratan. My code will work because there will be no OpportunityLineItems if there is no opportunity, right? So In another matter of Fact, This will work even if i use both Before insert and Before Update And If you give the Opportunity Stage as Closed Won in starting and After Created the Opportunity Line Items with Custom Field as Null, Then also my Error will show while saving the line items

Comment: @Subhash  **What you said is not possible** what do you mean? this is obvious since opportunity is creating then without creation process is completed . it's child can't be inserted. And related to getting the Id in before insert and then querying. I don't know how you are thinking it is correct way. no idea

Comment: @Subhash **If you give the Opportunity Stage as Closed Won in starting and After Created the Opportunity Line Items with Custom Field as Null, Then also my Error will show while saving the line items** ahh now it is the point. Trigger should be in update case not is insert case.. because while insert there won't be any OLI for that opportunity correct ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41398/discussion-between-subhash-and-ratan).

Answer (score 1):

So I guess you want to show en error when opportunity status gets changed to *Closed Won* and *Invoice_Date1__c* is empty?

Let's analyse your code line per line:

```
set < Id > id = new set < id > ();
```

You create a set of ids and call id just *id*. Not the best practice in my opinion, but whatever, it will compile and even work

```
OpportunityLineItem OL = [Select id, name, Invoice_Date1__c from OpportunityLineItem where Opportunityid =: id];
```

I guess your execution fails here with *System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject*? You are trying to query a single OpportunityLineItem where the reference to Opportunity is an empty set. You should do this query after the next loop(and use `IN` operator instead of `=` and use a `List` instead of a single OLI(or add LIMIT 1 to your query)):

```
for (Opportunity o: Trigger.new) {
    id.add(o.id);
}
```

Make sure to do this before querying your OLIs.

```
for (Opportunity o: Trigger.old) {
    if (o.StageName == 'Closed Won' && ol.Invoice_Date1__c == null) {
        o.StageName.addError('Your custom error message');
    }
}
```

If you loop through `Trigger.old`, `o.StageName` will be the stageName **before** the update, so if you only change it from *Open* to *Closed Won*, this will never be in the check.

You should compare old to new to notice the change of the field. And you should also use list of OLIs, because there can be multiple OLIs on one Opportunity.

Comment: I have updated my question with answer ..It helped.I have a query for you.If I use tigger.old in both loops I am getting this errr"System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors: Trigger.OpportunityStageWon: line 10, column 1" why?